# Loop through <li> and display list containing input value

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, append

I have a list of items like a todo list and i have a search input where i want users to search through the list'

I am using the keyup event and if input matches i am trying to use css to set the matched li to display:'' while the list items that do not match i want to set display:none.

so far i am able to console.log my results but cant effect changes to my li list as the css to set display none doesn't work.

here is my code below.

```js
    const Ul = document.querySelector('.clipBoard');
const search = document.querySelector('.search');
    
    
    array.forEach((item) => {
      let button = document.createElement('button');
      button.className =
        'list-group-item buttonLi';
      button.innerText += item;
      Ul.appendChild(button);
      
      
      //Search function
      search.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
        let filterValue = search.value;

        const li = Ul.querySelectorAll('.buttonLi');
        
        for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
          let List = li[i];

          if (List.innerHTML.indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
            console.log(li[i].innerHTML);
            li[i].style.display = '';
          } else {
            li[i].style.display = 'none';
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: Does `list[i]` actually provide you with an HTML element? If so you can console log the display property of the element before changing. I also think you should not change to `display = ''` but rather `display = block` accordingly

Comment: yes the list[i] does return an HTML element when i console.log it. display = block doesn't work either. as my <li> in browser remains the same. My intention is as user types, the <li> containing the typed letters remains while <li> not containing the typed letters are set to display = 'none', thus removed from the list.

Comment: I believe you are much better off writing a filter function and the result of the filter to be passed into an array, call it the `searchResults`, now when you start the `searchResults` will equal your original `array`, but as the user searches you will filter accordingly. Use `searchArray` as well to render dynamically the elements in HTML. Be sure to wrap your "search filter" code in a call back with a 300ms time out on key down for efficiency. All of this will eliminate you writing any CSS in Javascript. See the term `Debouncing` for more on that

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to assign an id to each element using the index at that level:

```
  array.forEach((item, INDEX) => {
  let button = document.createElement('button');
  var id = 'el-'+INDEX
  button.setAttribute("id", id);
  button.setAttribute("class", "list-group-item buttonLi");
  button.innerText += item;
  });
```

Then on your search function use that id to hide the elements

```
      search.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    let filterValue = search.value;

    const li = Ul.querySelectorAll('.buttonLi');
    
    for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      let List = li[i];

      if (List.innerHTML.indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
        console.log(li[i].innerHTML);
        // something like that
        var idToShow = '#el-'+i;
        document.querySelector(idToShow).style.display = 'block';

      } else {
        // something like that
        var idToHide = '#el-'+i;
        document.querySelector(idToHide).style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  });
```

I did not test this code, just trying to point you to an eventual solution!
You could also do the filtering on your array then for each search you re-render your list!